# Add a logo to the top of wordpress admin menu

Tags: wordpress, admin

I tried to add a logo to the admin menu as a menu item background image, but it seems not the best approach because when I try to add padding or margins to it, its position change and do not fit correctly, as shown in the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpH3q.png

And I used the following code:

```
/********************************************************/
/* INSERT ADMIN LOGO
/********************************************************/
add_action('admin_menu', 'shomtek_admin_menu');
function shomtek_admin_menu() {
    global $menu;
    $url = 'https://google.com/';
    $menu[0] = array( __('SHOMTek'), 'read', $url, 'shomtek-logo', 'shomtek-logo');
}


/*ADMIN LOGO STYLES*/
#adminmenu a.shomtek-logo{
    display: block;
    background: url(https://example.com/logo.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 140px 40px;
    width: 140px;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Can you please recommend the best approach to add a logo to the top of wordpress admin menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:
1- Create a menu on the top of the side menu:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page( 'Custom Menu Page Title', 'Custom Menu Page', 'manage_options', 'logo_based_menu', '', '', 1);
}
```

2- Add custom CSS code to print the logo inside that menu:

```
   function admin_style() {
     echo '<style>
        #toplevel_page_logo_based_menu {
    background-image: url('. get_field ("option", "logo_image") . ');
}
        #toplevel_page_logo_based_menu > a, #toplevel_page_logo_based_menu > a > div.wp-menu-image {
    display: none;
}
      </style>';
            }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect. I just added a " background-repeat: no-repeat; " not to repeat the background. Also, I would like to push this background image URL from an ACF image field option page: get_field ('logo_image', 'option'); Any thoughts how to pass this data in the code? Thank you

Comment: Just change this: "https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" with this "<?php echo get_field ('logo_image', 'option'); ?>",     by the way it would help if you hit the up triengle on my answer to mark it as "Useful", thank in advanced.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Mohamed Ali O.Ameur. I believe that php code will not work inside the script tag. Maybe saving data in a variable like this? $mylogo = get_field ('logo_image', 'option'); But then, how to pass this variable to the background-image URL in CSS?

Comment: it will work because you will insert the entire code with PHP so you can use PHP tag to dynamically get value from your database.

Comment: Would you be so kind to write an example of the code including the ACF field as the background-image URL? I tried one hundred times and it always throw PHP errors. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code for you, please use my edited answer code

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. But I already tried it like this and it does not work. I am running PHP 7.3. 'PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'logo_image' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' .  Any thoughts why?

Comment: @Horizzons I have fixed the code for you, it looks that I have reversed the parameters ("option", "logo_image") option should come first in ACF get_field() function.